# Отключен ли куки?

Tags: php

[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), я не знаю фреймворков, но у меня,естественно в индекс.пхп идет проверка на сессионную переменную, если оной не существует, тогда проверяются куки. если оных не существует, тогда... и т.д. В чем я неправ? [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto), тоже подключайтесь. В предыдущем вопросе у меня просто-напросто закончилась возможность давать комментарии.

Comment: @eicto, 

SELECT * FROM table_{$this->target}
это вообще зря, странная организация...

$this-target имеет значение либо news, либо articles, вместо двух контроллеров я сделал один - универсальный, который и посылает данные в соответствующую таблицу.

Comment: а чем news то от articles отличается ? :)

вообще проблема на ровном месте.

Comment: @eicto, ознакомившись с конфигурацией моего будущего проекта вы не нашли все же возможной уязвимости в реферрере? Я могу далее использовать данную технологию? Я не верю, что мой роутер.пхп может ошибиться.

Comment: @eicto, 

а чем news то от articles отличается ? :)
вообще проблема на ровном месте.

вот именно, проблема в отображении (view) Суть одна и та же, одинаковые названия полей таблиц, а отображение разное - там статьи, а там - новости. После обработки данных, откуда Контроллеру знать, куда вернуться?

Comment: @eicto,@VladD, я до сих пор не думаю, что можно обмануть Контроллер. У меня проверяются абсолютно все варианты request_uri, не может быть такого, чтобы как-то можно было бы взломать. И Модели тоже не дремлют, все гет и пост запросы язвительно потрошаться на адекватность принятых данных + скрытое поле с сессионным случайным значением...

Comment: > **откуда Контроллеру знать, куда вернуться**

зачем ему это вообще знать ?